# How to show reliability of Unix datagram socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix-socket, systems-programming

This a homework question relating to Unix socket and I tried to google to get the solution but I found nothing.

The question comes from **the Linux programming interface** ebook, 57.1

> we noted that UNIX domain datagram sockets are **reliable**. Write
> programs to show that if a sender transmits datagrams to a UNIX domain
> datagram socket faster than the receiver reads them, then the sender is eventually
> **blocked**, and remains blocked until the receiver reads some of the pending
> datagrams.

I think that I have to get the right system call to give a solution to this exercise

1. What is the function that already existed in Linux system call to block the sender while waiting for the receiver to receive packet?
2. How does the sender know that the receiver receives the packet successfully so that the system allows the sender to continue sending the new packet?

Comment: does it answer your question: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/udp-server-client-implementation-c/ ?

Comment: 1. There is nothing extra to do to get blocking behaviour. `send` will by default block. 2. That's handled by the OS. If the app is blocked on a send the OS will unblock it when it is able to send more.

Comment: Your task is to write a sender that just keeps sending with some way to tell whether a send blocks or not (e.g. print something out after each send). Then write a receiver that doesn't actually read from the socket until you tell it to (e.g. wait for keyboard input). The result should be that the sender eventually blocks. Then when you tell the receiver to start reading the sender should unblock and continue sending.

Comment: @kaylum your comment clarifies the requirement of the exercise, thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

1. All Linux functions that write data to a socket will block when the receiver is saturated, except the asynchronous engine functions (`io_submit()`, `io_uring_enter()`, etc.) and sockets explicitly configured to return an error instead of blocking (`O_NONBLOCKING` flag). The Linux functions that write to sockets are: `write()`, `send()`, `sendto()`, `sendmsg()`, `sendfile()` and its variants, like `writev()`, `sendmmsg()`, etc. It's pretty important to check if some socket was not blocked by the receiver before calling the send functions, or your program will block waiting for the socket to resume operation (although in this case it's exactly what the exercise asks).

> [send(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/send.2.html): When the message does not fit into  the  send  buffer  of  the  socket, send()  normally blocks, unless the socket has been placed in nonblocking I/O mode.

2. The receiver must tell the sender, either explicitly, or implicitly, that it's saturated. For example, TCP sockets will stop replying with acknowledgement packets. In the case of a Unix domain socket, communication is local to the server and consists of simple buffers. The receiver implicitly indicates saturation when free space in the socket buffer drops below a predefined "low watermark" value, by default 1 (`SO_SNDLOWAT` and `SO_RCVLOWAT` socket options).

> [socket(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html): Specify  the  minimum  number  of  bytes in the buffer until the socket layer will pass the data to the protocol (SO_SNDLOWAT) or the  user on receiving (SO_RCVLOWAT).

Comment: Not correct. (1) A send to a non-local UDP port will block while the socket send buffer is full, but it won't block while the receiver is saturated, as UDP has no means of communicating that to the sender (no receive window). (2) It is not *possible,* let alone 'pretty important', to 'check if some socket was not blocked by the receiver before calling the send functions', unless you mean adroit use of `select()/poll()/epoll()`.

Comment: You're right, my answer was too relaxed.